How to enable all Chrome GPU features (WebGL, Canvas) after they were apparently disabled?
I recently realized that video games run in Chrome had really bad frame rates. I opened up chrome://gpu and literally all the GPU features (WebGL, Canvas) were disabled or software only.
I have the AMD E1-1500 APU with Radeon HD Graphics, which is not very powerful but it should be able to run WebGL with hardware acceleration. I installed the latest drivers I could find but it did nothing.
Does anyone here know why this is happening or how to fix it?

You have enabled hardware acceleration within Chrome settings?

@ramhound yes, I have.It does nothing.

I also re-installed chrome but it didn't work

Sounds like your hardware isn't up to the task of supporting WebGL.

may have to do with this question about the same PC

@ramhound I guess I figured it out. Just needed to allow it anyways in chrome://flags

this also fixed the downloading  problem.

So when I asked if hardware acceleration was enabled, and you said it was enabled, did you verify before saying it was?

@ramhound yes. I even disabled and re-eneabled it to make sure.

I found the answer. I just went to chrome://flags and searched "gpu" then enabled unsafe hardware acceleration. It worked, my report now shows webgl as hardware accelerated: 
WebGL is now rendering without taking up my cpu:
